named config has recursion disabled, but query shows 'ra' bit
I have a bind nameserver running on CentoOS.
In my postfix logs I see errors from my RBL lists which point to nameserver config issues, which may relate to recursion.
Here are the named.conf lines related to recursion
recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";

recursion no;
allow-recursion { none; };
allow-query-cache { none; };

And here are query results from dig (domain name obfuscated)
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mail.acme.xxx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43458
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

Given the named.conf lines above, should I be seeing the 'ra' 'recursion available' bit in query results? If not, is there some other config option necessary?
